# How to get the href click event to work with a variable?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on jquery to click on the mail folder href links for my emails so I could do something. But I have got a problem with clicking on the href links because when I click on the href links, nothing will happens.

When I try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#'+folder+']', function(e) {
    alert("Now you are working on mailfolder");
});
```

Here is the PHP:

```
$folders_list = imap_listmailbox($mailbox, $mailserver, "*");
$folders_arr = array();
$key = array();
sort($folders_list);

if (is_array($folders_list)) {
    unset($folders_list[0]);

    $imp = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Archive.Important';
    $trash = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Trash';
    $sent = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent';

    $draft = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Drafts';
    $archive = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Archive';
    $junk = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Junk';
    $spam = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.spam';

    $key1 = array_search($imp, $folders_list);
    $key2 = array_search($trash, $folders_list);
    $key3 = array_search($sent, $folders_list);
    $key4 = array_search($draft, $folders_list);
    $key5 = array_search($archive, $folders_list);
    $key6 = array_search($junk, $folders_list);
    $key7 = array_search($spam, $folders_list);
    $key = [$key1, $key2, $key3, $key4, $key5, $key6, $key7];
    sort($key);

    foreach ($key as $val) {
        unset($folders_list[$val]);
    }

    foreach ($folders_list as $mailbox_name) {
        $mailbox_name = str_replace("{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "", $mailbox_name);
        $mailbox_name = str_replace("INBOX.", "", $mailbox_name);
        $folders_arr[] = $mailbox_name;
    }
}
sort($folders_arr);

<ul class="folder-nav inbox-divider">
    <li> <h4>Folders</h4></li>

    <?php
        foreach ($folders_arr as $folders) {
    ?>

    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <li>
            <a href="#<?php echo $folders;?>" target="_top" title="<?php echo $folders;?>"><i style="margin-left: -7px;" class="folder_icon"></i><span style="margin-left: 7px;"> <?php echo $folders;?></span></a>
        </li>
    </div>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
var hash    = window.location.hash;
var folder = hash.split('/')[0].replace('#', '');

$(document).on('click', 'a[href^=#'+folder+']', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    start_idx = 0;
    alert("Now you are working on mailfolder");


    if ($("#movetoFolder").css('display') == 'block') {
        $('#movetoFolder').hide();
    }

    if (openMail == true) {
        openMail = false;
    }

    if(window.location.hash == '#'+folder) {
        $("#click_nav_prev").addClass("disabled");
        $("#click_nav_next").removeClass("disabled");
        loadEmailBodyContent = false;
        $(".bottom_space").show();
        $(".emailMessages").hide();
        $(".emailBodyShowUp").hide();
        $("#opt_refresh").show();
        $('.tbody_maillist').show();
        mailfolder();
    }
    else
    {
        mailfolder();
    }
});
```

I have already tried this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mailfolder', function(e) {
....etc
});
```

It works fine, but it wont add the folder name in the url like http://example.com/#foldername when I click on the href links.

What I am trying to do is I want to get the href click event to work for any folder that I click on the a tag using with the variable so I can work on the code to fetch the data from the mail folders.

Can you please show me an example how I can get the href click event to work with the variable called `folder`?

Thank you.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're doing. Why are you ONLY binding the event handler to the link whose hash is the same as in `window.location`?

Comment: What is `.mailfolder`? Should that be `.folder_icon`?

Comment: Bind the event handler to all the links, and use `$(this).attr("href")` to get the folder name.

Comment: @Barmar The `.mailfolder` is the name of the class and the `.folder_icon` is used for the image.

Comment: @Barmar Do I need to use something like this? `var folder = $(this).attr("href");`?

Comment: Yes, something like that goes inside the event handler, rather than as a global variable.

Comment: @Barmar can you show me an example how i can get it to work? i have tried it and it dont work as nothing have come up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```js
$(".mailfolder").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var folder = $(this).attr("href");
  start_idx = 0;
  alert("Now you are working on mailfolder");

  if ($("#movetoFolder").css('display') == 'block') {
    $('#movetoFolder').hide();
  }

  if (openMail == true) {
    openMail = false;
  }

  if (window.location.hash == folder) {
    $("#click_nav_prev").addClass("disabled");
    $("#click_nav_next").removeClass("disabled");
    loadEmailBodyContent = false;
    $(".bottom_space").show();
    $(".emailMessages").hide();
    $(".emailBodyShowUp").hide();
    $("#opt_refresh").show();
    $('.tbody_maillist').show();
    mailfolder();
  } else {
    mailfolder();
  }
});
```

If you use a variable in an event delegation selector, the variable is expanded at the time you create the delegation, not every time the event occurs. So you can't have the delegation check automatically whether the link matches the current hash.

Another way you could do this is with a `hashchange` event handler. It could add a class to the link that matches the new hash, and remove the class from other links, and you can delegate to that class. Like this:

```js
$(window).on("hashchange", function() {
  $(".mailfolder").removeClass("current");
  $(`.mailfolder[href=${window.location.hash}]`).addClass("current");
});

// Special code just for current folder
$(document).on('click', ".mailfolder.current", function(e) {
  $("#click_nav_prev").addClass("disabled");
  $("#click_nav_next").removeClass("disabled");
  loadEmailBodyContent = false;
  $(".bottom_space").show();
  $(".emailMessages").hide();
  $(".emailBodyShowUp").hide();
  $("#opt_refresh").show();
  $('.tbody_maillist').show();
});

// Common code for all mail folder links
$(".mailfolder").on("click", function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  var folder = $(this).attr("href");
  start_idx = 0;
  alert("Now you are working on mailfolder");

  if ($("#movetoFolder").css('display') == 'block') {
    $('#movetoFolder').hide();
  }

  if (openMail == true) {
    openMail = false;
  }

  window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

  mailfolder();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I dont think you understand what I have already said before. I have already been used `$(document).on('click', ".mailfolder.current", function(e) {` but when I clicked on the a href link, it didn't add the hash at the end of the url like #foldername. So when I dont use the .mailfolder click event, it will add the hash at the end or the url but the jquery code won't firing. Any idea?

Comment: There's nothing in your original code that changes the hash of the URL. It just checks whether the anchor you click on matches the hash.

Comment: What does the `mailfolder()` function do?

Comment: it will call the ajax function to fetch the data from my other php script.

Comment: You can put `window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");` in the common code.

Comment: Barmar thank you, when I try the code i am getting this `#undefined`. Any idea?

Comment: You have that in the event handler, like I just added to my answer?